# Android eclipse - Making box increase in size with text

Tags: android, android-layout

I am displaying following rule in eclipse code. This rule is taking care of mostly all type of phones. But my problem is if the text is bigger like in this case it is wrapping around inside the box. Is there any way to make the box bigger automatically with increase in text?

```
TextView rule1


   //Add Rule 1
            rule1=new ImageView(this);      
            rule1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rules);
            if(w<340)
             {
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(310), height(44));
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(5);
                layout_params.topMargin=height(30);         
             }else if(w<=500)
             {          
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(469), height(64));              
                layout_params.topMargin=height(40); 
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(6); 
             }else
             {
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(774), height(92));
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(13); 
                layout_params.topMargin=height(60);
             }  
            list_layout.addView(rule1, layout_params);


            icon6=new ImageView(this);      
         icon6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.leader);
            if(w<340)
             {
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(31), height(33));
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(12);
                layout_params.topMargin=height(39);         
             }else if(w<=500)
             {          
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(43), height(44));           
                layout_params.topMargin=height(52); 
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(18); 
             }else
             {
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(57), height(60));
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(30); 
                layout_params.topMargin=height(78);
             }  
            list_layout.addView(icon6, layout_params);

            rule1 = new TextView(this);
                rule1.setText("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            rule1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            rule1.setTextSize(18);      
            rule1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Bold.otf");
            rule1.setTypeface(typeFace);
            if(w<340)
            {
                rule1.setTextSize(16);  
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(252), height(30));
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(40);
                layout_params.topMargin=height(39);         
            }else if(w<=500)
            {           
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(378), height(40));
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(72);
                layout_params.topMargin=height(52);             
            }else
            {
                layout_params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width(630), height(60));
                layout_params.leftMargin=width(120);
                layout_params.topMargin=height(78);                         
            }   
            rule1.setLayoutParams(layout_params);
            list_layout.addView(rule1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm think what you want is `WRAP_CONTENT` on your

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 150);
```

You can also set the `TextView` to `singleLine` if you like:

```
TextView.setSingleLine(true);
```